# why does both the block number is shown when I want to show the block with maximum departments?

Tags: oracle, top-n

I have a table department with 3 column(department_name , department_id, department_block_number) so I want to fetch the department_block_number in which maximum number of department is located ? I have two department_block_number 303, 202 and each has 4 and 2 departments respectively? how can i do it?

```
select q1.department_block_number , max(c)
(select department_block_number , count(department_id)as c from department group by department_block_number)q1,
group by department_block_number ;

select q1.department_block_number , max(c)
(select department_block_number , count(department_id)as c from department group by department_block_number)q1,
group by department_block_number ;
```

Now i want to show only 303 as it is the block number with maximum departments in it but my query is showing both 303, 202 please help me . If you know some other way so that i can fetch the result so please help

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Comment: ok but i am using oracle

Comment: So add the Oracle tag.  Don't just put a bunch of random tags.

Answer (score 1):

In standard SQL if you are looking for one row, you would do:

```
select d.department_block_number, count(*)
from department d
group by d.department_block_number
order by count(*) desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Some databases spell `fetch first 1 row only` as `limit 1` or `select top (1)` or in even more arcane ways.

In older versions of Oracle (`fetch` is supported in 12c+), you can do:

```
select department_block_number, cnt
from (select d.department_block_number, count(*) as cnt
      from department d
      group by d.department_block_number
      order by count(*) desc
     ) d
where rownum = 1;
```

Comment: Its seems you didn't understood my question i want  to display the block number which has maximum departments  in it

Comment: @sAnskarmodi . .. That is what this does.

Comment: and i want to show only block 303 but it is showing both 303 and 202

Comment: @sAnskarmodi That's the reason you should tag properly.  It's useless if someone post a solution, but you can't use it.